# I need to find a key in an array of objects and match it with Regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, object

I've lost over 3 days on this and still no success. This is probably like finding a needle in a haystack, but I still need to do this.

I'm trying to find the key in an array of objects and if it contains `(a)` or `(b)` set certain key to `true`.

However, I am making a mistake somewehere, but I have no idea where.

Here is what I have now:

```
let reg = /\((.+?)\)/;
let aggregatedArray: Array<any> = [];
const allWeeksDescription = this.selectedPlan.weeklyOffer;
console.log(allWeeksDescription);
let prop = 'description';
for (prop in allWeeksDescription) {
    allWeeksDescription[prop].forEach(function(k:any) {
          aggregatedArray.push(k.description);
          console.log(aggregatedArray);
     })
}
```

However, I receive this error in console (though, I do get a console.logged successfully after):

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: allWeeksDescription[prop].forEach is not a
>   function

All I need to do is find the `key ('description')` and if the value of it is matched with RegEx successfully, then set another `key ('exists')` to `true`. If not, leave it as it is - `false`. Matching should be done with RegEx stored in this variable:

```
let reg = /\((.+?)\)/;
```

In console I receive something like this:

```
{
   monday: [
         {
            description: "(a)",
            exists: false
         },
         {
            description: "(a)",
            exists: false
         },
         {
            description: "(a)",
            exists: false
         },
         {
            description: "(a)",
            exists: false
         },
         {
            description: "(a)",
            exists: false
         }
        ]
tuesday:  [
         {
            description: "test",
            exists: false
         },
         {
            description: "test",
            exists: false
         },
         {
            description: "test",
            exists: false
         },
         {
            description: "test",
            exists: false
         },
         {
            description: "test",
            exists: false
         }
        ]
     }
```

In conclusion I need to get the `description` `keys` and match them with `Regex`. If matched, a `key exists` should have a value of `true`. If not, it should be left as it is now - `false`.

Please help me with this, I've lost too many days over this.

Thanks guys.

Comment: @Kinduser, hi buddy. Could you please post a full working example as an answer ? Thanks mate.

Comment: I will need `allWeeksDescription` object (:

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't have it here..I'm at home. :( Is there anything you can do, please?

Comment: ValLeNain helped you already, I hope his solution will work for you, but if not - let me know - I will try to solve it.

Comment: I can't test is before tomorrow. I'm curious on VaILeNain's comment. Do you think keeping it in a separate file would be better?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to run a foreach loop over an anonymous type object. What you need to do is get all keys of the object and by assuming that they have the same structure, you need to ensure that they do match up with the pattern.

```js
let reg = /\((.+?)\)/;
let aggregatedArray = [];
const allWeeksDescription = this.selectedPlan.weeklyOffer;
console.log(allWeeksDescription);
let prop = 'description';
Object.keys(allWeeksDescription).forEach(function(k) {
    reg.match(allWeeksDescription[k]) && aggregatedArray.push(k.description);
    console.log(aggregatedArray);
})
```

Comment: Please make the matching logic. Thanks mate.

Comment: why setting `prop` to 'description' in a first place if you use the same variable to keep reference to `allWeeksDescription` indexes ? :)

Comment: Oh I missed that. I couldn't test the code at the first place because the questioner hadn't provide the data at the first place :)

Comment: Oh, my bad.. :)

Comment: Please change the exists to true. Thanks. )

Answer (score 1):

If the object you describe at the bottom of your post is `allWeeksDescription`, then you need to change your  `for` loop to:

```
  let matchingDays = []; // to keep a track of matching days
  for(let dayLabel in allWeeksDescription) {
      /* This is one day (= an array), in your first object */
      let day = allWeeksDescription[dayLabel];
      /* Go through all of its elements */
      day.forEach( d => {
        /* `d` is one element of the array */

        /* Check if it matches your regex */
        if(d.description.search(reg) !== -1) {
          /* do whatever you want here, you know that the description matches your regex */
          d.exists = true;
          matchingDays.push(day);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Wait.. !== matched the regex?? How is that??

Comment: I'm using this function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) which tells if a string matches a Regex (returns the index of the match if there is one, -1 otherwise).

Comment: This is the first time I've seen it implements. Hopefully your solution will work. Could you please complete it, so that exists is set to "true"? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I did. But I'm not quite sure how you'll use this info in the other parts of the code. It's time consuming to loop over your object again and again to check if `exists` is set to true, better to keep those days in a separate object.

Comment: I'm not looping, this is being sent to the database and stored there. :) But, for the sake of learning, how would you keep it in a separate object? What is the best solution?

Comment: you could declare a separate array, and store in it the days which have a matching description (call `yourArray.push(day);` where I do `d.exists = true;`)

Comment: How would you do that, if that's not much of a hassle for you? :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much! ;)

Comment: @ValLeNain, are you still here?

Comment: @eric.dummy yes :)